# Pandas read_sql Challenging syntax for postgres query

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I am querying a postgres db using python/pandas with sqlalchemy.  I have an sql query that looks like this:

```
    SELECT table_name
    FROM fixed_602fcccd0f189c2434611b14.information_schema."tables" t 
    WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    and table_schema='di_602fccd10f189c2434611be9'
    and (
    table_name like 'general_journal%'
    or table_name like 'output_journal_line%'
    or table_name like 'output_journal_tx%'
    or table_name like 'flats%'
    )
```

I've tested it in dBeaver and it works perfectly.  I am now trying to pass the same query through pandas read_sql as follows:

```
from_string = pg_db + '.information_schema."tables"'
print(from_string)
pg_query = queries.id_tables.format(from_string,di_id)
```

The idea is that I construct the query with variables 'pg_db' (string) and 'di_id' (string) as I make a series of queries.  The problem is the query returns empty array when done this way.  No error is thrown.

I suspected the challenge is the "tables" attribute that when pandas interprets the query eg. strips off the ", but that doesn't actually seem to matter.  Any thoughts on how to make this work with pandas?

UPDATE:
I have tried parameterized and met with the same problem.  It seems to boil down to the FROM parameter gets passed in with double quotes.  I have tried to strip these but it looks like pandas appends them anyways.  In principle double quotes should be fine according to postgres docs but that doesn't seem to be the case even when doing the query in dBeaver.  If I pass in the query via pandas as it is written at the top of this post, no problem.  The challenge is when I try to use variables for the FROM and table_schema parameters, I get syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem disappeared when I removed the parentheses I put around the 'or' statements.  I think the message is to pay attention to how you construct the query eg. form and join all the strings and variables before passing them to pandas.

That said I have used parentheses with much more complex queries in pandas and they were not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest that you use a parameterized query for input but in some cases its just easier to use a built in function `repr()`

```
s = "SQL sometimes likes \"here\" and %s \"now\" problems"
print(repr(s))
```

gives

```
'SQL sometimes likes "here" and %s "now" problems'
```

Comment: repr() causes a syntax error to be thrown.  not familiar with parameterized query I will look in to that.

Comment: yup.  repr() adds the single quotes and that messes up the syntax according to the error message

Comment: I updated the OP that I'm querying a postgres db and using sqlalchemy.